# Using Ajax call to update a Django view

Tags: ajax, django

I am new to Django, and am stuck attempting to get a variable sent from ajax to be used in the Django view. My view:

```
def index(request):
  if (request.is_ajax()):
    username = request.GET['user']
  else:
    username = ''
  context = {'user':username}
  return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

and the ajax:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: '/index/', 
  type: 'GET', 
  data: {user: response.name, page: page} 
});
```

My issue is that `username` does not update in the view, based on the ajax call. I know the ajax call is working properly, because upon looking at the network response it is passing the proper updated username.

What I believe is happening is that the view is loaded, then the ajax call occurs and updates username, but the view is not re-rendered and thus won't change. I have tried putting another render after getting the username, but that did not change anything, and I have also made a separate view for handling the ajax call, but that doesn't seem to work either, since the view always loads without ajax request being true.

What is the way to get this working? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you get from the ajax response? What are you doing with it? If you add `complete: function(resp) { ... }` to your ajax request, what is `resp.responseText` inside that function?

Comment: Sorry, also a bit of a newbie with ajax as well. If I console.log the response text, it logs the updated index page with the new `username`. So should I just reload the page on success?

Comment: You would probably replace the DOM with the new DOM. But that is an extremely inefficient way. You really need to return just the username, and update that. Look at Brandon's answer for help. where he has `console.log(json.user);` Do something like `$('#username').html(json.user)`

Comment: Getting closer. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you intend to return a response via Ajax that JavaScript can then use to update your DOM, you need to return an `HttpResponse`, preferably in JSON format, which can be passed to a handler in your $.ajax call. Example:

```
import json

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        username = request.GET.get('user', '')
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)

        # do whatever processing you need
        # user.some_property = whatever

        # send back whatever properties you have updated
        json_response = {'user': {'some_property': user.some_property}}

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(json_response),
            content_type='application/json')

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'user': ''})
```

Then in your JavaScript, you can do:

```
$.get('/index/', {user: response.name, page: page}, function(json_response) {
        console.log(json_response.user.some_property);
});
```

With this approach, a normal GET request to your view returns a rendered HTML template. For an Ajax request, the view returns an HttpResponse in JSON format that gets passed to the callback in the jQuery $.get call.

Comment: I'm getting an error that 'response' is undefined, coming from the `json.dumps(response)` line.

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault. I did some refactoring on the name of the response variable. I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: Awesome, that did update the DOM properly. But is there any way I can have the updated username be used in the view? Like somehow get that value and use it for the index view. The index, in the actual app, is running a query with the username as the argument, and so I'm wondering how to get this new username for the later query. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: You can do whatever you'd like with the username sent via ajax in your view. Just add your code before the `HttpResponse` is returned. I'll update the example code.

Comment: That did it. Since the query would return a queryset object, would I need to then make the `json_response` a dict of all the values? i.e. I can't simply add `user` to the dict, but each property independently, as you did above with `'user': {'some_prop': user.some_prop}`?

Comment: That's correct. The `user` object wouldn't have much context in JavaScript :)

Answer (score 2):

To send data to django view via Ajax call, you need to add data to Form and then send in ajax request.

Example:
**My view.py :**

```
def index(request):
"""
View function to handle Ajax request for image Link.
:param request: Ajax request data.
:return: image URL.
"""
if request.is_ajax():
    try:
         username = request.POST['username']
         # perform operations on the user name.

    except:
        e = sys.exc_info()
        return HttpResponse(e)
    return HttpResponse(sucess)
else:
    raise Http404
```

My template index.html

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Index</title>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
                 var data = new FormData();
                 var username = $('#id_username').val()
                 data.append('username', username);
                 $.ajax({
                     type: 'POST',
                     url: 'getuser/',
                     data: data,
                     processData: false,
                     contentType: false,
                     success: function(json) {
                         alert(json);
                     }
                 })
             });
         });
                 
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Index</h1>
      User name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="id_username">
      <input type="submit"  id ="btnSubmit" name="submit" value="Send Test Push">
   </body>
</html>
```

After this you need to add ajax call url into urls.py.